# Tell constructor im using task without telling which method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to define a task (or thread) in my constructor, but start the task (or thread) with its method in a button-event.

So I want something like this:

```
Task SendTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(());
private void SendFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendTask.Sendfiles();
}
```

My Method:

```
public void SendFiles()
{
    try
    {
        tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
        if (tcpClient.Connected)
        {

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Chudnofsky\\Desktop\\Projekt\\Neu\\Messwerte.txt"))
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    string line;
                    line = reader.ReadLine() + Environment.NewLine;
                    stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                    byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(line);
                    stream.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Datei konnte nicht gelesen werden!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You will want to manage the task, but to just define and start it you probably want: `var SendTask = new Task(Sendfiles); SendFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { SendTask.Start(); }`. Also, `lock(this)` might not won't work for you, you usually want an object common to each task to lock against. With 10 tasks you just get 10 different locks, but if there's contention between each `SendFiles()` method then you want just 1 lock.

Comment: Whats wrong with doing `Task SendTask; private void SendFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { SendTask = Task.Run(SendFiles); }`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Well the behavior when you click the button twice is completely different in the two cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contructor, like this:

```
Task SendTask = new Task(new Action(SendFile));
```

and in the event handler simply start it with checking [it's status](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskstatus.aspx):

```
private void SendFilesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (SendTask.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
    {
        SendTask.Start();
        SendFilesButton.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

You should avoid the `lock (this)` construction as it will lock your UI form.